# Where can I get obsolete MOSFET's from?

Tags: mosfet-driver

I have a Fusion5 tablet which is not working. There is a mosfet which gets very hot when I plug it in so 1st thing I want to replace. But I'm looked online and can not find where I can get a replacement. Is there places which sell there or can I get an alternative? Marking on one below which seems to be the same is 8029.

Thanks!

P.S to the left of the mofset is the DC jack. When I plugged in I used micro USB to charge as currently don't have the correct power adapter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It could be something after the mosfet that is drawing too much current and causing it to get hot. Replacing it looks necessary, but might not be enough. If you can figure out the part number and important specs based on what type of circuit it's used in, you can just buy a newer better one. You'll need to obtain and understand the schematic first though.

Comment: If you have the part number you can get the datasheet so you have the specs and can find a suitable replacement.

Comment: Part number of the motherboard? All I have is the tablet model is fwin232 and the systemboard QL-M E328832 rohs 19.50. I have put in pic of board in main post.

Comment: Part number of the part.  There's a really good chance that it's the same as the one next to it, which, fortunately, isn't burnt.

Comment: A basic rule of electronics repair is that if you've got a part that burnt up, it almost certainly didn't do so spontaneously -- something *else* broke and took it out.  You want to track down that root cause.  At the very least, get a handful of replacements.

Comment: My issue here is I have no idea where to get the burnt out part to even move forward. All the chip says is 8029, I can find no schematics. Google of 8029 I get TPC8029 which is obsolete and can not get hold of anymore.

Comment: Two similar MOSFETs pleaced adjacently, hmmmmm, smells like a battery management circuit or some synchronous DC-DC converter. OP, can you please take a picture of the 10-15 components in the neighborhood of this pair of MOSFETs and post it in the edited version? Maybe someone could take a guess at the functionality and recommend a replacement part number.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig Added more images. Thanks

Comment: Great, please read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two MOSFETs, placed in proximity to each other near the charging port. The visible MOSFET labeled 8029 is most likely a p-channel MOSFET [SSC8029GN2](http://www.sscsemi.com/upfile/2020/07/17/SSC8029GN2%20V2.0.pdf). You are right that this is a rare transistor, even I couldn't find it easily. But good thing is, it has typical characteristics (20 V, 7.5 A), so it is easier to find replacements.

From here we can guess the following two things.

1. These two are connected back-to-back as a protection and control mechanism for the charging management system.
2. These two have the same part numbers.

If these two assumptions are correct, then you can use the following transistors in place of the burnt MOSFET. All of these meet or exceed the important specs of the 8029 MOSFET and are pin-to-pin compatible. But please beware that there may be other components on the board that may be damaged.

- [PMPB24EP](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nexperia/PMPB24EPX/?qs=byeeYqUIh0OOUOUVz8DEWg%3D%3D) 30 V, 9.5 A
- [PMPB16EP](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nexperia/PMPB16EPX/?qs=Cb2nCFKsA8qwqmK0FL64WA%3D%3D) 30 V, 10.6 A
- [DMP2023UFDF](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/DMP2023UFDF-7/?qs=26fMNUst%2FUAaikdU7qbq4Q%3D%3D) 20 V, 7.6 A
- [DMP2039UFDE4](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/DMP2039UFDE4-7/?qs=5vZCdhuZeNOC8LTx3UEA1Q%3D%3D) 25 V, 7.3 A

There are a lot of other options as well that may meet the specs and would be pin compatible. You can refer to 8029's datasheet for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm new to this, but I will replace and see where that take me.

Also to note from the top left on the 2nd image you should see the power button is missing. I would guess its the same as the volume buttons as the place on the board looks the same but it is missing so can not confirm 100%. Where can I get these from?

Comment: I would like to know how do you plan to unmount the burnt part and mount the new one. Because this thing has its solder pads under it.

Comment: I was planning on using my Hot Air Gun Station. That not going to be possible @abdullah-baig ?

Comment: That depends on your level of expertise. It's a tricky procedure. You may de-sold a lot of nearby components attempting to fix this one. If you have at least some experience with SMD components, then it's a risk worth taking. Otherwise take it to some repair shop etc.

Comment: I'm no expert but want to improve my skills, I'm not fussed if I destroy the board. This is more of a hobby thing than a need to actually getting a working tablet. :)

Comment: Then go for it. Godspeed!!